My Dell OptiPlex 990 boot is very slow and I don’t know why
I have a Dell OptiPlex 990 with good specs like an SSD, i5 2500, and 8GB RAM.
The system is extremely slow when booting from a Ventoy USB flash drive to install Windows or Linux, hanging for a few minutes before the installation starts; afterwards, the process goes a lot faster:

I have the default UEFI firmware settings, UEFI
The only thing I changed is the controller mode to AHCI from RAID. I really don’t know what the system is doing - why is doing that?

Any ideas what is happening?

@AndreiChiper Sorry to say this but it HAD low to medium specs more than a decade ago and also keep in mind Optiplex is the business oriented Dell's line of products, performance never was the priority. That said, the major bottleneck is the old USB2.0 ports. The slowness you're experiencing when booting USB installers is due to that, nothing else (it's somehow faster after it loads most of the data into RAM).   maybe a pci to usb 3.0 board or a device like that should be a better choice? Indeed, it may speed things up for anything USB that has been designed for v. 3.x but (...)

(...) on the other hand, it's trowing money to an about to become obsolete desktop. Anything you can buy nowadays will have better spec'ed USB ports so your PCIe card will be redundant if not a nuisance. You should have realistic expectations when dealing with old machines.

Thank you for the responses. @ChanganAuto I see that. Indeed is a pretty old machine. I wanted to give like a new life to it as a NAS to store some data. After long waiting I could install something on it. Now it works. Thank you again!

As a final answer to this question. Here I go.
Due to the low machine specifications, as @ChanganAuto said in comments and some research on the internet, the computer is not usable for the expectations I had in my mind. Still, the computer can be used as a station to work on, doing light tasks, editing documents, watching videos.
I have installed OpenMediaVault operating system and done RAID 1 for mirroring. The performance is terrible. It took me almost one day to do all the configurations and wait for the machine to complete tasks. As for the speed, I tried to save a copy of a 5 GB Windows ISO file on it and the write speed went somewhere around ~48 Mbps. Not fast at all.
I just wanted to see if it can get something done.
In conclusion, don't jump to buy old stuff in the hope that it will work just fine. Buy it only after a lot of research and only if you have real expectations from it.
Thank you!

Satisfação, que está mensagem encontre todos bem...
falo do Brasil,
O pegar dois equipamentos como estes, Dell optplex 990 me deparei com as mesmas condições mencionadas, muito lento na inicialização mesmo apos upgrade para SSD.
descobri que em ambas situações a bateria da Bios estavam zeradas o que leva o padrão de
fabrica instalação para RAID, descobri que mesmo alterando para AHCI e não removendo o cabo de energia mesmo assim, sem trocar a bateria Bios volta para RAID fazendo que tanto a instalação quanto execução do sistema fique lenta. Portanto troquem primeiro a bateria da Bios e alterem o Setup para AHCI mode também na Sequencia Boot desmarque a opção de USB RAID cliquem em aplicar. Espero que ajude. No meu caso Resolveu.
Com um abraço,
Att. Márcio Silva. Clean Computer

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
